# Qframe/QGroupBox mouse hover Qt

Tags: qt

How can the size of frame or Group Box be increased on mouse hover in Qt?I want to change the size of a frame when the mouse hovers over it?Please help me as i am new to QT.Can we achieve it by using stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set mouse tracking to true. [`void QWidget::setMouseTracking(bool enable)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)
2. Reimplement [`virtual void QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) and resize widget there.